# this.setState in setTimeout in react

Tags: reactjs

Function to update state:

```
animate() {
 setInterval(function(){
   setTimeout( this.setState({
     a: '123'
   }), 1000);
 }, 4000);
}
```

The method called:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.animate();
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function
```

Then the next code tried:

```
animate() {
 setInterval(function(){
   setTimeout( () => {this.setState({
     a: '123'
   })}, 1000);
 }, 4000);
}
```

And the next error was:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this2.setState is not a function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem stems from your definition of `setInterval`.

When you do `setInterval(function() {...})`, the `this` keyword is no longer bound to the React component but to the function it is called within because of the introduction of the new scope.

You can either switch it to:

```
animate() {
  const self = this

  setInterval(function() {
    setTimeout(() => self.setState({ a: '123' }), 1000)
  }, 4000)
}
```

This way `self` is assign to the React component value of `this` before the new scope is introduced, or you can use all arrow functions to preserve the `this` keyword referencing the component:

```
animate() {
  setInterval(() => {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ a: '123' }), 1000)
  }, 4000)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer submitted by m_callens is the proper one, I'll add this possibility using `bind` as well, for those who use pre-ES6 JavaScript.

```
animate() {
    setInterval((function(){
        setTimeout((function() {this.setState({
            a: '123'
        })}).bind(this), 1000);
    }).bind(this), 4000);
}
```